# Displaying an image using PySimpleGUI without having to use an event listener

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am trying to display an image in my GUI using PySimpleGUI. I know that I could just do sg.Image('image_file') when setting up the GUI itself, but I also want to resize the image. I can't figure out how to do that. I've tried doing sg.Image(size=(300,300),'image_file') but that does not work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sg.Image(size=(300,300),'image_file')` should be some sort of syntax error. Have you tried `sg.Image('image_file', size=(300,300))`?

Comment: oh yep that did it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sg.Image(size=(300,300),'image_file')
```

should be some sort of syntax error. Try

```
sg.Image('image_file', size=(300,300))
```

Answer (score 6):

Steps to resize and load into `sg.Image`

- Resize PNG file to size (300, 300) by using `PIL.Image`
- Convert image to `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage` after window finalized
- update image in `sg.Image`

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from urllib import request
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# Get one PNG file from website and save to file
url = (
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/master/"
    "images/for_readme/Logo%20with%20text%20for%20GitHub%20Top.png")
headers = {
    'User-Agent': (
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
        '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36')}
req = request.Request(url, headers=headers)
response = request.urlopen(req)
if response.status != 200:
    print("Failed to load image from website !")
    exit()
data = response.read()

filename = "example.png"
with open(filename, "wb") as f:
    f.write(data)

# Resize PNG file to size (300, 300)
size = (300, 300)
im = Image.open(filename)
im = im.resize(size, resample=Image.BICUBIC)

sg.theme('DarkGreen3')

layout = [
    [sg.Image(size=(300, 300), key='-IMAGE-')],
]
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, margins=(0, 0), finalize=True)

# Convert im to ImageTk.PhotoImage after window finalized
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im)

# update image in sg.Image
window['-IMAGE-'].update(data=image)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```