# Pysimplegui resizing images

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

I'm trying to resize images in [pysimplegui](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/) however it crops the images instead of resizing.

My image element is written as:

```py
ui.Image('{filename}'), size=(50,50)))
```

Which results to something like:

[image]

While the original looks like:

[image]

I've seen somewhere else that suggests PIL ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67080573/17714994)). However, this looks a lot longer than i liked and was wondering if there is an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Peace
hi
to resize an image you need to take advantage of the pillow library, but you need to import other libraries too in order to convert it into bytes if needed, here is an example:

```
import PIL.Image
import io
import base64

def resize_image(image_path, resize=None): #image_path: "C:User/Image/img.jpg"
    if isinstance(image_path, str):
        img = PIL.Image.open(image_path)
    else:
        try:
            img = PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(image_path)))
        except Exception as e:
            data_bytes_io = io.BytesIO(image_path)
            img = PIL.Image.open(data_bytes_io)

    cur_width, cur_height = img.size
    if resize:
        new_width, new_height = resize
        scale = min(new_height/cur_height, new_width/cur_width)
        img = img.resize((int(cur_width*scale), int(cur_height*scale)), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    bio = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(bio, format="PNG")
    del img
    return bio.getvalue()


ui.Image(key="-PHOTO-",size=(50,50) #after some change
elif event == "-IMG-": # the"-IMG-" key is in [ui.I(key="IMG",enable_events=True), ui.FileBrowse()]
        window['-PHOTO-'].update(data=resize_image(value["-IMG-"],resize=(50,50)))
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Helloooo, heres my workaround to resize images in pysimplegui:

1. read the image stored in the path 'old_path'.
2. resize this image to my desired dimensions.
3. store the resized image in a folder as a 'png' file.
4. finally display the resized image.

```
 old_path = os.path.join(
                values["-FOLDER-"], values["-FILE LIST-"][0]
            )
            #  read image using old_path
            im = cv2.imread(old_path)
            #  resize image to desired dimensions
            im = cv2.resize(im,[700,500])
            # save image to temporary folder (new_path) as png
            new_path ='temp_storage/image_to_show.png'
            cv2.imwrite(new_path,im)
            # update window with new resized image
            window["-IMAGE-"].update(new_path)
```

if you need the full code let me know. The image storing folder only stores the image to be shown, it will override every time you choose a new image so no worries about images pilling up.

cv2 needed for reading, resizing and writing.  (or PIL)

Goodluck!